# 16-bit float MPI_Reduce?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, precision

I have a distributed application that uses `MPI_Reduce()` for some of the communication. In terms of precision, we get fully accurate results with 16-bit float numbers (half-precision).

**To accelerate the communication (reducing the amount of data movement), is there a way to call `MPI_Reduce()` on 16-bit float numbers?**

---

(I looked at the MPI documentation and didn't see any info about 16-bit floats.)

Comment: Hi, do you mind accepting my answer below? Thanks!

Comment: Done. I had been hoping to experiment with your code before accepting it... but it'll probably be a couple more days before I get around to trying it.

Comment: I wrote a bunch of stuff on this topic on GitHub (https://github.com/uber/horovod/issues/278#issuecomment-405701026) that I am too lazy to copy here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MPI` standard defines only 32-bit (`MPI_FLOAT`) or 64-bit (`MPI_DOUBLE`) floats in its internal datatypes.

However, you can always create your own `MPI_Datatype` and your own custom reduce operation. The code below gives some rough idea of how you can do this. Since it is unclear which 16 bit float implementation you are using, I'm going to refer to the type simply as `float16_t` and the addition operation as `fp16_add()`.

```
// define custom reduce operation
void my_fp16_sum(void* invec, void* inoutvec, int *len,
              MPI_Datatype *datatype) {
    // cast invec and inoutvec to your float16 type
    float16_t* in = (float16_t)invec;
    float16_t* inout = (float16_t)inoutvec;
    for (int i = 0; i < *len; ++i) {
        // sum your 16 bit floats
        *inout = fp16_add(*in, *inout);
    }
}

// ...

//  in your code:

// create 2-byte datatype (send raw, un-interpreted bytes)
MPI_Datatype mpi_type_float16;
MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_BYTE, &mpi_type_float16);
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_type_float16);

// create user op (pass function pointer to your user function)
MPI_Op mpi_fp16sum;
MPI_Op_create(&my_fp16_sum, 1, &mpi_fp16sum);

// call MPI_Reduce using your custom reduction operation
MPI_Reduce(&fp16_val, &fp16_result, 1, mpi_type_float16, mpi_fp16sum, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// clean up (freeing of the custom MPI_Op and MPI_Datatype)
MPI_Type_free(&mpi_type_float16);
MPI_Op_free(&mpi_fp16sum);
```

Comment: You are missing a call to `MPI_Type_commit()`. It should also be possible to abuse the language interoperability feature in newer MPI libraries and utilise the Fortran `REAL*2` type by something like `mpi_type_float16 = MPI_Type_f2c(MPI_REAL2);`. It still needs a user-defined reduction operator since the standard ones do not operate on `MPI_REAL2`.

Comment: It looks like `REAL*2` is not supported on x86, at least by GCC and Intel.